# How to display a value in a variable in textbox?

Tags: javascript, cordova

I am new to script.
I need to display the value in textbox i have created the textbox inside the  tag of  my html file.
The processed value is in "var a" variable.
How can i set the value in textbox

Comment: Some code would help. And Java != JavaScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With JavaScript something like

```
var a = 'bla bla bla';
var textBox = document.getElementById("TextBoxID");
textBox.value = a;
```

Maybe you want to wrap it in some function (pass the text instead)

```
function addText(text) {
    code above;
}
```

Dont forget to bind it with some kind of event (example `onClick`)